# solving a differential equation in form of integrals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have given the differential equation $x'=\alpha(t)x+\beta(t)$.

How can you write the solution $x$ in form of integrals without $x$?

I've tried multiplying with the factor $\exp\left\{-\int\alpha(s)\,ds\right\}$ but it doesn't get me anywhere.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ignore $\beta(t)$ you get :
$$\frac {x'}x=\alpha(t)$$
$$\log |x|=C_0+\int \alpha(t)\;dt$$
So that $\ \displaystyle x=C\;e^{\int \alpha(t)\;dt}$

Using variation of constants (supposing $C$ a function of $t$) we get :
$$x'=(C'(t)+\alpha(t)\,C(t))\;e^{\int \alpha(t)\;dt}=\alpha(t)x+\beta(t)$$
After simplification this gives :
$$C'(t)\;e^{\int \alpha(t)\;dt}=\beta(t)$$
that we integrate as :
$$C(t)=D+\int \beta(t)\,\left(e^{-\int \alpha(t)\;dt}\right)dt$$
with the result :

$$x(t)=\left(D+\int \beta(t)\,\left(e^{-\int \alpha(t)\;dt}\right)dt\right)\;e^{\int \alpha(t)\;dt}$$

Comment: thanks. But how do you get $x'=(C'(t)+\alpha(t)\,C(t))\;e^{\int \alpha(t)\;dt}=\alpha(t)x+\beta(t)$ by using variation of constants?

Comment: @sheldoor: Start with $\ \displaystyle x=C(t)\;e^{\int \alpha(t)\;dt}$, compute the derivative $\frac d{dt} x$ to get the left equality then use your initial equation at the right.